# How do I get the Impossible, It Can’t Be. Is it? achievement?

Tags: payday-2

How do I get the achievevment *Impossible, It Can’t Be. Is it?*

- Secure the rare Almir’s Toast.

What is the Almir's Toast?

Comment: The heist was literally just released.

Comment: @MattR: ​​​​so?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I guess the fact that it was asked when the heist was out?

Comment: @MattR Would you have preferred I asked it before the heist came out? The moment the heist came out I was already in an OvK WXmas heist, trying to see if others knew about this, but no one really knew what it was.

Comment: A reasonable time would have been better, rather than directly after the came out.  Overkill can, and have, been cryptic in how certain achievements have been reached.  You didn't even give enough time to actually try between release and post.

Comment: @MattR Considering it was answered not even 6 hours after being asked, I think that was a pretty reasonable time. There is no such thing as "reasonable time" because (1) that's completely subjective and (2) gamers move *fast*. There's a reason why our policy is "as long as people can play it, questions about it are allowed".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You find it in random present cases, I guess. I opened one and Almir's Toast was inside. Careful, though. It makes you move super super SUPER slow while carrying it.

[image: Screenshot showing Almir's Toast]

Answer (score 2):

I just got the ach.
You need to open the xmas presents found on the ground, mine was in the presents around the plane.
I got one on the second present i opened but i think it has to be on overkill diff
[image: Proof]

Comment: No, it does not need to be overkill difficulty. I've found it on one of the two lowest difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

I found it on normal difficulty. Be sure to stay at the lumber mill's ziplines so you can move to the helicopter as soon as you hear Bane tell you where it is going to land. (Otherwise the chopper will be gone before you get there)